# How to store an array of objects in Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is my code. I am trying since a couple of days to create an Array of Objects, which I will then store in Local Storage. Here is the problem, I need to first Get the existing value from Local Storage.

I then need to add the new data object to the existing array. I then convert it into JSON so that I can store it back in the local storage.

```
onRegisterSubmit(){
    const user = {
        a: this.a,
        b: this.b,
        c: this.c,
      id: Date.now()
    }    

   var abc = [];
   var get =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
   abc = [get];
   abc.push(user);

   localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(abc));

   console.log(JSON.stringify(abc));
   console.log(get);
  }
```

I want the JSON to be an array of objects like this,

```
[{"hour":1,"minute":21,"ampm":"PM","repeatDays":[],"message":"","todayOrTomorrow":"Tomorrow","isRepeatMode":false,"isEnabled":false,"id":"1493797882440"},{"hour":1,"minute":24,"ampm":"PM","repeatDays":[],"message":"","todayOrTomorrow":"Tomorrow","isRepeatMode":false,"isEnabled":false,"id":"1493797896257"},{"hour":6,"minute":14,"ampm":"PM","repeatDays":[],"message":"","todayOrTomorrow":"Tomorrow","isRepeatMode":false,"isEnabled":false,"id":"1493815470408"}]
```

This is my JSON.

```
[[[[[[[{"id":1493820594019},{"id":1493820606448}],{"id":1493820609111}],{"id":1493820610150}],{"id":1493820610553}],{"id":1493820610827}],{"id":1493820611015}],{"id":1493820612018}]
```

I've been trying for several days and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the problem? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: When onRegisterSubmit is executed, this become the structure. [[[[[[[{"id":1493820594019},{"id":1493820606448}],{"id":1493820609111}],{"id":1493820610150}],{"id":1493820610553}],{"id":1493820610827}],{"id":1493820611015}],{"id":1493820612018}]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Yes but I hardly understood the replies. I did try them. What are my mistakes.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The issues with that code are:

1. You're wrapping the result you get in an array, but in theory, you want to *already* have an array.
2. <s>You're storing `user`, not `get` or `abc`.</s> *(You removed that with an edit.)*

To store the array, do what you're doing:

```
localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
```

To get the array:

```
users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]");
```

Note how that provides a default (empty array) if `getItem` returns `null` because we've never stored our users there.

To add a user to the array:

```
users.push({id: 1, foo: "bar"});
```

---

Example ([live on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/436xupte/) *[Stack Snippets don't allow local storage]*):

```
(function() { // Scoping function to avoid creating globals
    // Loading
    var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]");
    console.log("# of users: " + users.length);
    users.forEach(function(user, index) {
        console.log("[" + index + "]: " + user.id);
    });

    // Modifying
    var user = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
    };
    users.push(user);
    console.log("Added user #" + user.id);

    // Saving
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
})();
```

That shows you the list of current users in the console, adding one each time you refresh the page.

Comment: @Neha: Good deal. The main points above are still valid, though. Added an example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. I have a question; can be added but how can a user be removed?

Comment: @Emre6 - Do the same thing, but in the middle instead of `users.push(user);` do `users = users.filter(u => u.id === userIdToRemove);` or similar. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please show me where I went wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/9qjL1gho/5/

Comment: @Emre6 - You didn't, I have a typo in my comment above, it should be `!==` instead of `===`. With `filter`, you specify what items to **keep**. So if we want to remove the item with the ID `userIdToRemove`, we need `.filter(u => u.id !== userIdToRemove)`. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:-
link https://jsfiddle.net/sureshraina/nLexkyfw/1/

```
var mydatas = new Array();
        mydatas[0] = "data";
        mydatas[1] = "data1";
        mydatas[2] = "data2";

        localStorage["mydatas"] = JSON.stringify(mydatas);

        var datas = JSON.parse(localStorage["mydatas"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage).

You can't store Objects, you have to store a String. So the workaround is to stringify your Object before you store it (for example, you could use change it to a JSON object, store it, and read it again when needed).

Comment: When you downvote an answer, please post a comment explaining why you downvoted it, as it serves few purpose otherwise.

Comment: Your answer is correct though, I did just that and that is how I did it. I did an up-vote, no idea why someone gave a down vote.