# Video Player Local Storage For Each Video

Tags: javascript, video, local-storage

i have movie website and my video player local storage just saving one video src.

i want to use different src for each movie video

> ```
> window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
>     let setDuration = localStorage.setItem(
>       "duration",
>       `${mainVideo.currentTime}`
>     );
>     let setSrc = localStorage.setItem(
>       "src",
>       `${mainVideo.getAttribute("src")}`
>     );
>   });
>
>   window.addEventListener("load", () => {
>     let getDuration = localStorage.getItem("duration");
>     let getSrc = localStorage.getItem("src");
>     if (getSrc) {
>       mainVideo.src = getSrc;
>       mainVideo.currentTime = getDuration;
>     }
>   });
> ```

Comment: The easiest modification would be to append an index to your keys, e.g., src-1, src-2, src-n.  Yet, if you have many videos then you'll want to store them as an array of objects.  See related question: [How to store an array of objects in Local Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762363/how-to-store-an-array-of-objects-in-local-storage)

Comment: i do not know how to do this

Comment: The question does not provide enough detail to suggest a specific solution.  However, I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5r9msvzw/2/show) that shows you how to save and restore the video state.  Click the edit button on the page to view the code.